# Optimize outer join in oracle view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g.

I have a big table with 1016736 rows and another small table with 2007 rows. I want to join these two tables into a view.

I join these tables like below.

> where big_table.id = small_table.id (+)

I assume, this will form the view by looking at the small table 1016736 times. Is there a more optimized way to do this?

The queries are slower with the way it is now and i want to make it faster.

Any idea would be appreciated as i am new to Oracle.

--- EDIT ---
This is the script of my view.

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col100, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 
from big_table a, small_table b where a.col1 = b.col1 (+)
```

Comment: If you want to make something faster you need to post your full query, the indexes on the tables and the explain plan of the query.... It's almost impossible to help you effectively without them.

Comment: I am not looking to make any specific query faster. i am trying to make simple 'select count(*) from view' faster. if u want the view's query, it is just a select from both tables with all columns where bug_table.id = small_table.id(+)

Comment: So your query is _just_ `select count(*) from big_table b left outer join small_table s on b.id = s.id`?

Comment: This is the script of my view. `select a.col1, a.col2, a.col100, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from big_table a, small_table b where a.col1 = b.col1 (+)`

Comment: This means _"give me everything from big table and everything that exists in small table that also exists in big table"_, which means you need to full-scan the big table and get everything from it, so the only way to improve it would be to add an index on `b.col1` if only a tiny percentage of the `b.col1` is the same as `a.col1` and even then it might make no difference as the table is tiny  and if might be more efficient to full-scan it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to select from the view without any predicates placed on either table then Oracle is going to estimate the join cardinality based on the number of distinct values and the maximum and minimum values in the join columns, and any histograms present -- the number of rows projected could be anywhere from zero to 1016736 x 2007 (when the join columns each have the same single value for every row)

The join type will then depend on this estimation.

Typically you would see a hash outer join for this type of query, which is very efficient and barely more cost than reading the data required by the query projection.

For a simple count(*), if you have indexes on the join columns and the large table's join column is constrained to NOT NULL (or you use some method to ensure that the null values are included in the index) then they could each be fast full scanned and the results hash outer joined. Performance would be extremely good.

If you have particular queries that are slow then an execution plan is required to help in optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

The join is Ok, just create an index on "Id" for each table.

Try updating the statistics:

for each table:

```
ANALYZE TABLE XXXX_TABLE DELETE STATISTICS;

ANALYZE TABLE XXXX_TABLE COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

Comment: This should be rather fast 1 million records is not that much. try updating the statistics (check my updated answer)

Comment: I did `EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('schema', 'table');` already. In fact, it is scheduled now and runs every mid night. Is yours different from mine?

Comment: GATHER_TABLE_STATS just updates the table stats, doesn't include the indexes'. I suggest you delete statistics once.

Comment: However, maybe it's just a memory or hardware issue, maybe tablespace too fragmented and a bunch of many other issues. Perhaps you need the services of a DBA.

Comment: `GATHER_TABLE_STATS` does include the indexes.  By default it will use `AUTO_CASCADE`.  In theory Oracle will automatically determine if index statistics are necessary.  [In practice](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12226/does-dbms-stats-auto-cascade-ever-work), it will always re-gather index stats.  `DBMS_STATS` replaced `ANALYZE TABLE` a long time ago.